# Is Jiren the strongest mortal character in Dragon Ball Heroes?

Tags: dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-heroes

So apparently a character (which I dont remember the name) reads Hit's mind and he finds out Hit thinks Jiren is the strongest mortal in all the universes. Hit has seen UI Goku and Hit has fought Goku SSB Kaioken. Also supposedly this character which reads Hit's mind is shown to think the same later (perhaps due to what he readed from Hit's mind).

In the anime we see Jiren fighting Cumber at an apparently same level and Cumber claims "they are even". In the anime Cumber is defeated by Ultra Instinct Goku, though he didnt turn into SSJ3. I believe in the manga he did. Also Gogeta SSJ4 Xeno with much struggle managed to win a beam clash agaisnt Cumber SSJ3.

We also see Jiren being in a similar level with Zamasu, but later we see him overpowering Zamasu.

As far as I remember, candidates to be equally or stronger than Jiren are Cumber, UI Goku, Xeno SSJ4 Gogeta, and perhaps some others such as this guy who is able to bring him to the ground with a gravity related power, Fu perhaps, and may be some others I'm not aware right now.

Is Jiren the strongest mortal character in Dragon Ball Heroes?

Comment: Note: There was a specific conversation in the show where a character was asked who the strongest mortal was to which he answered Jiren. So this question isn't really opinion based.

Comment: @GaryAndrews30 I'm not sure if a character in the story saying he thinks someone is the strongest isn't still an opinion, unless he used a definite basis in his comparison and not just because of what that character thinks. In your answer, the information says it could or could not be the case and this might vary for other readers depending on what they observe, which could lead to opinion-based answers. Not sure what the others think but this is what I think...

Comment: @W.Are Lol That doesn't really make sense. The character making a claim is something from the writers and not opinion based. Goku having an opinion, isn't the same as you or I having an opinion as the former is something the writers want to indicate. Power scaling has been done in this fashion throughout the franchise for a Long time. Like the time Goku and Vegeta compared Dabura to Cell back in DBZ. The person here might have perhaps forgotten that Hit hasn't witnessed Goku at his full power which would then make Hit's statement accurate.

Comment: @GaryAndrews30 What I'm trying to say is that a character can say someone is the strongest based on what he/she knows, but what if this character hasn't witnessed or known others who might be stronger than Jiren? I'm also confused by power scaling: if, from what I understand, it gives a way to determine who's stronger, then why can't a direct answer be given? Your answer concludes on a might-or-might-not-be-the-case because there are still uncertainties. Observations on which character could or could not be stronger could vary depending on the reader/watcher.

Comment: @W.Are When a character speaks with reference to another character, it is the writers trying to state to the viewers how strong a particular character is. When Goku/ Vegeta says they've never seen someone as strong as Jiren, that essentially means Jiren is stronger than Fused Zamasu or antagonists faced before and it has nothing to do with personal opinion and is simply common sense. The reason a direct answer cannot be given is that Hearts is also a mortal and we haven't witnessed his full power.There is also an obvious indication of Goku being much stronger and to what extent, is uncertain.

Comment: @W.Are Also, the statement made by Hit was a "Factual statement" and the same is made by "Hearts" in the game where Jiren is referred to as the "strongest mortal across the multiverse". However, hearts appears to be stronger in the anime and these statements were made by fighters who haven't witnessed Goku fight with his newly acquired level of power. Hit made a statement that Jiren is the strongest based on the fact that he fought the latter himself and witnessed Goku fighting Jiren. One must be stupid to think Hit's opinion is personal when he obviously favours Goku over Jiren.

Comment: These questions are complicated because sometimes there are specific answers and sometimes there arent and people answers with opinion based answers. If I'm asking it's because I don't know if something else has been shown about a character in all the media which shows if that character is stronger or not than other. For example, it was stated by a writer than Goku SB kaioken x20 and Vegeta Super Saiyan Blue evolution are equally strong. If I make that question here and someone ignores that it's going to mark the question as opinion based but it has a valid answer and it isnt opinion based

Comment: And yes what the characters say in Dragon Ball is meant by the authors to give a sense of who is stronger than who at a given moment, but Dragon Ball as other shows make several characters continuosly surpass each other and what's worse it's that writers and authors sometimes ignore what others wrote or what's worse they forget what themselves wrote at a given moment making to know who is stronger than who difficult, but there are scales in Dragon Ball, no one would doubt a super saiyan is stronger than Chiaotzu

Answer (score 1):

Hit hasn't witnessed the might of Mastered Ultra Instinct Goku. So it would make sense he would think Jiren was the strongest mortal at that point in time. Taking that into consideration, is he the strongest mortal? Maybe. However, it seems very likely that Goku should be as strong or possibly stronger than him in his Completed Ultra Instinct Form, especially since there has been the indication that he's able to tap into Ultra Instinct. As for the others you mentioned, Jiren didn't seem fazed by anyone he fought apart from *Hearts* when he lowered the gravity around him. So Jiren, for now, should be one among the top 3 strongest mortals.

Comment: updated question title just in case

Comment: @Pablo Answer updated.